# Wrap Grouped ListBoxItems (Stackpanel Issues)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, listboxitem

I am trying to wrap grouped listbox items in a listbox.  I am using a stackpanel within a wrappanel to accomplish this, but the issue is that the stackpanel is being selected in the listbox, causing issues.  Here is an example of the problem:

[image: Example of issue]

**Here is my code, simplified:**

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel ItemWidth="120" Width="400" IsItemsHost="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <StackPanel>
        <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource label}">Header 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel>
        <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource label}">Header 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
    </StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using a grid?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your issue correctly i have a working solution.

The way you have designed is incorrect.

Please see my code and let me know if this is what you wanted.

```
   <ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" x:Name="ListBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding ListToBind}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel ItemWidth="120" Width="400" IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">

                    </ListBox>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>



This is my UI and here is connecting Data model. I set the datacontext in code behind and fill up a model.
```

Code behind looks like this

```
       public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListToBind = new ObservableCollection<DataModel>
        {
            new DataModel { Header = "header 1",
                Collection = new List<string>{"Item 1","Item 2", "Item 3"}},
            new DataModel { Header = "header 2",
                Collection = new List<string>{"Item 1","Item 2", "Item 3"}},
            new DataModel { Header = "header 3",
                Collection = new List<string>{"Item 1","Item 2", "Item 3"}},

        };
        this.DataContext = this;
        var para1 = new Form1();
        var check = ListBox1;
   }
```

And here is the data model

```
 public class DataModel
{


    public string Header { get; set; }

    public List<string> Collection { get; set; }


}
```

And this is how it looks like after running

[image]

Comment: This might work, and I will have to test it.  However my goal is to have just one continuous list for one listbox, so that the user is forced to pick only one selection.  I realize I could add code to deselect the other lists, but there must be another way to accomplish what I have above, without the need to create multiple lists.

Comment: So are you saying you want to select the entire list or just one element from entire list. for example you should be allowed to select header  2 and in header 2 item 2. if you select any other item from header 3 then header 2 should be deselected. is this what you want to implement ?

Comment: Your scenario is what I am looking for.  I select an item from header 2.  Then if I select an item from header 3, the item from header 2 is deselected.  I suppose I could code the deselection, but then I may as well create x different lists, as opposed to my one list that I currently have.  I was just curious if there was a way to "group from left to right" using one list.

Comment: Okay Mike will think over it.